# How do you update a django template context variable after an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a table Product that shows information of a group of products.

```
    <table id="item_table" class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Date</th>
            <th colspan="6">Product name</th>
            <th colspan="2">Category</th>
            <th colspan="2">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in product_list %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{{ item.date }}</td>
                <td id="item_name_format" colspan="6">{{ item.name }}</td>
                {% if item.category_id %}
                <td id="item_name_format" colspan="2">{{ item.category_id.level1_desc }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                <td id="item_amt_format" colspan="2">${{ item.amount|intcomma }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am using the below Ajax call you update the table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Submit post on submit
$('.item_num').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var item_num = $(this).attr('id');
    update_item(item_num);
});

function update_item(item_num) {
    console.log(item_num) // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'update_items', 
        data: { 'item_num': item_num },

        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            ???$('item_table').product_list = result;???
        },
... more code
```

How do I update the variable product_list with 'result' from my Ajax call?

This should update the table right?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to serialize your new product list items, pass them back into your ajax callback, and then iterate the table body, creating a new row for each new item via JS. It is certainly possible, but @doniyors answer is smarter and more efficient.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you cannot this way. Better way would be to load that part of your html via ajax.

your ajax view:

```
def update_items(request):
    product_list = your_data
    return render(request, 'table_body.html', {'product_list':product_list})
```

your main html:

```
<tbody class="table_body">
   {% include 'table_body.html' %}
</tbody>
```

table_body.html:

```
{% for item in product_list %}
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">{{ item.date }}</td>
     <td id="item_name_format" colspan="6">{{ item.name }}</td>
     {% if item.category_id %}
      <td id="item_name_format" colspan="2">{{ item.category_id.level1_desc }}</td>
     {% endif %}
      <td id="item_amt_format" colspan="2">${{ item.amount|intcomma }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

your ajax would look like this:

```
function update_item(item_num) {
    console.log(item_num) // sanity check
    $('.table_body').html('').load(
        "{% url 'update_items' %}?item_num=" + item_num
    ); // <--- this code instead of $.ajax(lala)
```

you use this [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) here

Comment: Thanks.  What do I change in my AJAX function to return the HTML?  right now, the html is showing up in the developer's console, but not updating in main.html.

Comment: @HC sorry, forgot that part. updated the question. I didnot test it, let me know if it doesnot work

Comment: @HC dont forget the new css class `table_body` :)

Comment: Thanks! it mostly works.  A few follow-up questions: 1) Assuming item_table has a span of 12 (bootstrap), table_body is now render with a span of 8 or 9. I wonder if this method changes the formatting of bootstrap? It's not obvious why the formatting would change to me... 2) In this implementation, if the user presses the back button, the user can never get back to the same state.  Is there a way to do this with Ajax or another way to save the current state?

Comment: I discovered why the rendering looks a bit funny.  For some reason, the updated table has / in the code.  For example in colspan: <td colspan="\&quot;2\&quot;">Jan. 5, 2016</td> .  Do you know why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: I think when you use AJAx, it creates a unique url, which saves the state of the page. If a user selects product 1, that is a diff url than prdct 2, even though only part of the page html is updated. If a user were to press the back button they can go back to the pg where the table is updated for a certain prdct they have selected.  I may be missing something but the solution above doesn't change the overall url so users can never press the back button to the state when they selected before. Is there a way to make the url unique like in an AJAX call? or how to implement with AJAX?

Answer (score -1):

you need first to create model for your product items

then in your views.py home function, load items from database and passing it to context

example:

```
myProduct = Products.objects.all()
context = {'myList': myProduct}
return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

then add this java code to your templete and call it if user want to add item or remove it from card list

like:

```
onClick="toggleCardItem({{item.id}})"
```

then

```
function toggleCardItem(itemId){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'client/add/card',
        data: {'id': itemId},
        success: function(res){
             location.reload();
        }
     })
}
```

python templete:

```
{% for item in myList %} etc.....
```

now on your views.py create

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_to_card(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       item_id = request.POST.get("id")
       key = request.session.session_key
       if key:
           find = Clients.objects.filter(session_key=key)
           if find.exists():
               find = find.get()
               card = find.card_list if find.card_list else "[]"
               card = eval(card)
               item_id = int(item_id)
               if item_id in card:
                   card.remove(item_id)
               else:
                   card.append(item_id)
               find.card_list = card
               find.save()
               return HttpResponse("Success")
           else:
               raise PermissionDenied("This page is private, you not allowed to entered!!!")
       else:
           raise PermissionDenied("This page is private, you not allowed to entered!!!")
   else:
       raise PermissionDenied("This page is private, you not allowed to entered!!!")
```

import python library:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect, csrf_exempt
```

now in url.py add

```
path("client/add/card", views.add_to_card, name="Add to Card"),
```