# JSON serialisers and alternative http responses with Django

Tags: json, django, post, django-serializer, django-1.11

I'm trying to create a filter system on a click event - using an AJAX post method to update the context that is shown on the template.

I'm currently using:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

To return a response with a context object. However, this doesn't quite work with certain object types:

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

I know there's something regarding serialisers but I'm currently unable to either a.) use them correctly or b.) use them at all.

For some context I'm passing filter variables to the view with the AJAX post method - then:

```
posts = Post.published.filter(category__name__in=category_filter_items)
```

And adding this to my context:

```
context['posts'] = posts
```

Would anyone know the correct way to update the context is such a manner?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know that once the Django template is rendered, you can't dynamically modify its context without rendering it again. See [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-django-template-language-for-python-programmers).

Before modifying dynamically your template, you should really consider a way to filter your data by calling a view that renders the template again with the context you need.

## Option 1: Render the template again

```
def my_view(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all()
    # TODO: Filter the posts against the request
    template = loader.get_template('template.html')
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

## Option 2: Modify your template dynamically

If you're sure that modifying your template dynamically is your best / only choice, you've got different ways to achieve this.

One of them is changing your template via jQuery, loading a subtemplate that is rendered by your filtering view. Take a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166013/how-do-you-update-a-django-template-context-variable-after-an-ajax-call).

Another way is to get your filtered data via a JSON Api and make sure your template is updated accordingly. You may want to use Angular for instance, which uses a [MVVM architecture pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

### How to serialize models in Django?

Django provides [serialization of models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) as a core feature.

Serializing your models to JSON is as simple as:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.all())
```

If you need to implement an API with serialization of models AND filtering, you may want to use [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: ValueError: The view app.views.blogs didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Did you return the response (return HttpResponse(context, content_type='application/json')?

Comment: I know how to return json ... I wanted to update context {% for post in posts %} < posts doesn't change (!!)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166013/how-do-you-update-a-django-template-context-variable-after-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

What about use JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse? also you need to define a serializer for Post model.