# Ajax call with django on bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, ajax, django-templates

Problem Statement : I am not getting a way by which I can load the whole chart html in the div by calling a function from views.py and passing the context to the refernece_page.html without refreshing the page.

I have a chart just like any stock chart. I have a durtion dropdown for which I have used a Bootstrap dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown show " style="float:left; ">
      <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <span id="selected" >Event Time</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Hour</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 day</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Week</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Month</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I want to make to update the dive which has the chart in place without refreshing the page. For this I have a "per_hour_data" function in views.py which loads with default value of duration "1 Hour".

```
def per_hour_data(request, app_id, record_count):
    app_detail = get_object_or_404(AppDetail, app_id=app_id)
    line_data = line_chart_data(app_id,record_count)
    app_data = AppDetail.objects.all()
    context = {
    'line_data':line_data,
    'app_detail': app_detail,
    'record_count':{'1day':'1day', '1hour': '1hour', '1week':'1week', '1month':'1month'},
    'app_data':app_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'status_monitor/reference_page.html', context)
```

The reference_page.html has the chart data and where I am parsing the context. Now I want to do something like when I select different duration then the chart should get updated without refreshing the page. I thought of doing this using AJAX. so i wrote another function

```
def update_chart(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        app_id = request.GET.get(app_id)
        record_count = request.GET.get(record_count)
    app_detail = get_object_or_404(AppDetail, app_id=app_id)
    line_data = line_chart_data(app_id,record_count)
    app_data = AppDetail.objects.all()
    context = {
    'line_data':line_data,
    'app_detail': app_detail,
    'record_count':{'1day':'1day', '1hour': '1hour', '1week':'1week', '1month':'1month'},
    'app_data':app_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'status_monitor/reference_page.html', context)
```

and the AJAX call as

```
{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function () {
  var record_count = $(this).text();
  var app_id = getElementById('#app_id');
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/update_chart/',
    data: {
      'record_count': record_count,
      'app_id' : app_id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.error_message);
    },
    error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
  });

  });
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('status/<app_id>/<str:record_count>/' ,views.per_hour_data, name='per_hour_data'),
path('update_chart/', views.update_chart, name='update_chart'),
```

]

I am not getting a way by which i can load the whole html in the div by passing the context to the reference_page.html.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your code, which you want to load without refreshing main page, in `reference_page.html`  and render it using jQuery load function. Don't use `$.ajax`

I am assuming your main html is `main.html`

Your main view

```
def per_hour_data(request, app_id, record_count):
    app_detail = get_object_or_404(AppDetail, app_id=app_id)
    line_data = line_chart_data(app_id,record_count)
    app_data = AppDetail.objects.all()
    context = {
        'line_data':line_data,
        'app_detail': app_detail,
        'record_count':{'1day':'1day', '1hour': '1hour', '1week':'1week', '1month':'1month'},
        'app_data':app_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'status_monitor/main.html', context)
```

Your main.html template

```
<div class="dropdown show " style="float:left; ">
  <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <span id="selected" >Event Time</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Hour</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 day</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Week</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1 Month</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="chart">
    {% include 'reference_page.html' %}
</div>
```

javascript function - call is on dropdown value change

```
function update_chart(record_count, app_id) {
    $('.chart').html('').load(
        "{% url 'update_chart' %}?record_count=" + record_count + "&app_id=" + app_id
    );
}
```

your ajax view

```
def update_chart(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        app_id = request.GET.get(app_id)
        record_count = request.GET.get(record_count)
    app_detail = get_object_or_404(AppDetail, app_id=app_id)
    line_data = line_chart_data(app_id,record_count)
    app_data = AppDetail.objects.all()
    context = {
        'line_data':line_data,
        'app_detail': app_detail,
        'record_count':{'1day':'1day', '1hour': '1hour', '1week':'1week', '1month':'1month'},
        'app_data':app_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'status_monitor/reference_page.html', context)
```

You can also refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166013/how-do-you-update-a-django-template-context-variable-after-an-ajax-call)